# how to hook azure api management api to underlying service?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I've added an API mapping for an existing service through my API Management instance.  I did this by importing the swagger json for the service. This appears to provide an additional mapping layer that serves as an interface into the underlying service.

Now I need to figure out how to configure the APIM API to call the underlying service so the API provides a useful hook into the underlying service implementation for consumption by developers.  After this is configured what would be steps for a developer to consume a service operation?

Comment: Is the "Rewrite URL Template" input field used to manage the redirect of the API mapping to the underlying service implementation?  It seems like this would be inferred automatically through Swagger?  Or is the wireup to the underlying service handled in a different way with "Rewrite URL template" only used to reformat the url for special cases?

Comment: I figured out that "Rewrite Url Template" is used to translate a proper Web API uri into whatever uri is used by the underlying service.  So the gap for me now is:  What is the process for hosting/uploading a WCF service to Azure?  The rewrite url appears to be within the server context.